# Search PHPMYADMIN Database for similar entries

Tags: mysql, sql, phpmyadmin

So this is the next step in my banning of accounts process, my original question was:

> So I have database with a table called users.. and in that table there is a column named IP and I want to find users with the same IP and ban them.. So how can I search the database for IP's that are the same?

And the answer was

> But basically this should work:
>
> select distinct IP, count(id) from users group by IP having count(id) > 1.
>       This will return all IP addresses with a count of > 1

And it did, now I have a list of IP's, I would like to see if there is a way to extend the statement so that:

```
if IP is greater than 1 UPDATE WHERE IP > 1 SET banned TO '1'`
```

Comment: Bad idea. Ban one college student and the whole college gets banned as well. IP is not a good measure for unique accounts.

Comment: Learn SQL;  Don't ask for SQL code.

Answer (score 0):

You can't update/edit your current table on which you are running queries.
You can alternatively store you temp data in temp table and use that table. Here, dst_tbl is tepm table;

```
CREATE TABLE dst_tbl select distinct ip, count(id) from users group by IP having count(id) > 1;
update users set banned =1 where ip in ( select ip from dst_tbl);
```

Although this is a example only. Users connecting through a proxy connection (Colleges) will have the same public IP. You must not implement this in your original code.